# Nodemailer cannot send emails to STMP server if running within Docker container

Tags: docker, nodemailer

I have an Node.js application sending e-mails with nodemailer to a SMTP server. This runs fine. But if I put the very same application in a docker container, the server declines to process the e-mails, responding with an error:

```
error: Error: Invalid login: 535 Incorrect authentication data
     at SMTPConnection._formatError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:528:15)
     at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/usr/src/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:1231:30)
     at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:319:22)
     at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:669:16)
     at SMTPConnection._onData (/usr/src/app/node_modules/smtp-connection/lib/smtp-connection.js:493:10)
     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)
     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

Does anybody know, if nodemailer within Docker requires any change in the configuration?

It is not an issue with the credentials. It is the same application with the same nodemailer configuration and the same credentials. The only difference is where the application runs (directly on the server or within a Docker container).

Also, I can ping the SMTP server, if I run the ping command within the Docker container. So, the server is reachable, but the application cannot connect to it.

Comment: Try running your container in `network_mode: host` and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was a problem with the password. More details:

The SMTP credentials are stored in an .env file. The password was escaped in this file:

```
PASSWORD='secret'
```

With the change to Docker and Docker Compose, the same .env file was used and the credentials submitted to the app in the `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
 environment:
        SMTP_PASS: ${PASSWORD}
```

Now, Docker Compose seems to automatically escape all environment variables. Now the password used in the nodemailer config was wrong, because it got single quotes at the start and end of the string.